# WiFi problems in windows 7 boot camp

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, bootcamp

I have a mid-2012 retina 15" MBP.  WiFi works fine in OS X, but in boot camp (windows 7 x64):

- I can see, but cannot connect to my 5 GHz network (n only, 40 MHz channel)
- I can connect to 2.4 GHz (BGN, 20 MHz channel), but the connection has latency spikes and frequently drops.

Wifi chip is Broadcom BCM43xx, router is Linksys E3200 running firmware 1.0.04. Signal strength does not seem to be a factor. I've also tried updating the boot camp drivers, device manager shows "Broadcomm 802.11n Wifi Adapter", driver version 6.30.223.215. Is there something I could tweak to improve compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too. I've solved this with updating the driver but with an old driver Broadcom version **5.106.199.1** (11/13/2012). Here is the steps :

1. Left click on your wireless adapter in Device Manager
2. Choose "Update Driver Software.."
3. Pick "Browse my computer for driver software"
4. Pick "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
5. Choose "Broadcom....Version: 5.106.199.1 [11/13/2012]"
6. Next.. Wait for installing.. Finish (no need for restart)

Comment: Where can I find this old driver?

Comment: it's already there, have u tried it?

Comment: Oh! I've re-readed your comment, and I understood to auto-search from hard-drive ^^'